# Should I bother to edit questions that will be closed?

Tags: discussion, edits, closed-questions

Sometimes there are extremely* bad posts that not even God can fix. They are doomed to be closed and remain silently in the depths of Stack Overflow where nobody in his right mind will ever see them again.

Extreme poorness isn't easy to find, but when found:

> Should I bother to edit this question even knowing its destiny is irreversible?

I am mainly concerned about the Disk Space. Obviously if such thing didn't exist I would make the edit without weighting any pros and cons

<sub>* Not to confuse with fixable questions.</sub>

Comment: *I am mainly concerned about the Disk Space* - now come on. With 2 **TB** costing only 110 euros, you shouldn't worry about disk space :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I am mainly concerned about the Disk Space...

Maybe my sense of humor is getting dull, but don't worry about that.

> Should I bother to edit this question even knowing its destiny is irreversible?

Yes, if you can improve the question then by all means: do it - even if you *believe* the "destiny is irreversible". Sometimes your edit will make the difference between a question being closed and downvoted and getting a good answer.

That being said, don't feel obligated to bother editing if you truly feel it's not salvageable, or it's so bad that you can't understand what the OP is actually trying to communicate. If you *want* to and you have the ability to improve any post, there's no reason not to.

Improving posts is a volunteer job, and it always helps and never hurts.

Comment: +1 for _Sometimes your edit will make the difference..._ did happened few times to me that spelling / personal stuff cleanup and breaking text into paragraphs really made a reasonable question from what looked a pile of crap

Answer (score 12):

I wouldn't rest this on the standard of how "extremely poor" the question is. If the question is on-topic, then editing it can help it immensely. However, if the question is off-topic or not constructive, I would personally not bother to edit it. These questions are destined to be not only closed, but also deleted. It's up to you as an editor if you want to spend the time editing posts that will likely not be around much longer.

However, when it comes to suggested edits, I oftentimes hold them to a much, much higher standard for improvement in order for me to accept them (tag-only edits = instant reject). I reject most suggested edits on closed and soon-to-be-closed questions.